# Getting a 'float' error trying to sort input by age group

Tags: python

When checking my code copied from a program called flowgorithm using onlinegdb, I'm getting the "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable".

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong during the 'if' statement, but I get this feeling I'm close in my logic.

```
def readerAge():
    pass
    
    return readerAge

# Main
readerAge = [0] * (4)

print("Please enter reader's age: ")
readerAge = float(input())
if readerAge < 20:
    readerAge[0] = readerAge[0] + 1
else:
    if readerAge >= 20 and readerAge <= 29:
        readerAge[1] = readerAge[1] + 1
    else:
        if readerAge >= 30 and readerAge <= 39:
            readerAge[2] = readerAge[2] + 1
        else:
            if readerAge >= 40 and readerAge <= 49:
                readerAge[3] = readerAge[3] + 1
            else:
                if readerAge >= 50:
                    readerAge[4] = readerAge[4] + 1
print("Please enter reader's gender (M/F/NB): ")
readerGender = float(input())
print("Please enter the reader's marriage status (Single/Married/Divorced): ")
readerMarigStat = float(input())
print("Please enter reader's yearly income: ")
yearlyIncome = float(input())
print("Demographic analysis")
print("Number of readers under the age of 20: " + str(readerAge[0]))
print("Number of readers between 20-29: " + str(readerAge[1]))
print("Number of readers between 30-39: " + str(readerAge[2]))
print("Number of readers between 40-49: " + str(readerAge[3]))
print("Number of readers over the age of 50: " + str(readerAge[4]))
```

Comment: Your line: `readerAge = float(input())` means that `readerAge` is no longer a `list`, but a single `float` instead. You will no longer be able to index it.

Comment: So, your error message says `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`. You describe this as "a 'float' error", but that doesn't make any sense. It is a type error, which is why it says `TypeError` at the front. It is an error that has to do with the type of something. `'float'` is a type that things can have (you presumably understand this, because otherwise, what are you expecting `float(input())` to mean?). "Subscriptable" means exactly what it sounds like: able to have a subscript applied to it.

Comment: Subscripting is the thing you do when you select an element from a list or a dict. Do you see why it might be a problem to try to do that when you have a float instead?

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [to use a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)  
Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. 
Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these intermediate results with expected results. 
Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem. 
Then ask a _specific_ question if you are still confused by your code's behavior. It's not okay to dump your code and expect other people to debug it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```py
readerAge = [0] * (4)

print("Please enter reader's age: ")
readerAge = float(input())
if readerAge < 20:
    readerAge[0] = readerAge[0] + 1
```

You create a list variable and then override it with a float variable. (and trying to access a float at a specified index does not make sense, hence the raised error)

Use a separate variable for storing the input and keep `readerAge` (or vice-versa) as a list:

```
readerAge = [0] * (4)

print("Please enter reader's age: ")
age = float(input())
if age < 20:
    readerAge[0] = readerAge[0] + 1
```

***EDIT:*** I did not look at the end of your code and this is not directly related to the question but you're also converting string input to float and that will raise an  error as well. Just use `input()` without `float()` if you expect to get actual words and not numbers entered.

```
print("Please enter reader's gender (M/F/NB): ")
readerGender = float(input())
print("Please enter the reader's marriage status (Single/Married/Divorced): ")
readerMarigStat = float(input())
print("Please enter reader's yearly income: ")
yearlyIncome = float(input())
```